# jasmine unit test error when adding Cookie Service

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

while writing jasmine unit test case for one of my angular 2 component, if I add CookieService in provider list then all remaining other component unit test cases are failing. If I remove CookieService from provider list then test cases are working fine. You can check this at plunker [cookiservice unit test](https://embed.plnkr.co/fsL4K5v9lrDAylXFdry3/).my component spec file code:

```
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {beforeEachProviders,beforeEach,describe,expect,it} from 'angular2/testing';
import {MyComponent} from '../src/my.component';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

describe('MyComponent', () => {  
  beforeEach(() => {
    setBaseTestProviders(CookieService);
})  
it('sample test', () => {
       expect('test').toEqual('test');
});    
});
```

Comment: At a guess, CookieService requires the rest of its module to work correctly. Why not inject a test double of it instead, `{ provide: CookieService, useValue: ... }`? Also your setup seems a bit weird, what's with the wrapper functions and why set up the test bed in two separate places?

Comment: even I tried stub value like { provide: CookieService, userValue: cookieserviceStub }, but still same issue. For readability called TestBed two times.

Comment: ...and what *is* that issue? Give a [mcve] including the failure/error. And FWIW the unconventional structure, especially with inconsistent indentation, makes it much *less* readable to me.

Comment: I added minimal code. you can try this spec file. if you remove CookieService from provider, test case will success. if CookieService is there then test case will fail.